# How to redirect Apache "Index of ..." page?

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I am trying to achieve authenticated file listing in Apache using PHP via Apache's [autoindex module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

The way I imagined it was to have Apache run a PHP script as a [header file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername). I've managed to get Apache run PHP correctly for the header file and it detects login cookies fine, too. But it seems that Apache runs the header file as a separate request which means if I try to send a redirection header from PHP it is not run.

My (simplified) Apache config:

```
DocumentRoot "/path/to/files_root"
Alias /~extra "/path/to/extra-data"

<Directory "/path/to/extra-data">
    Options -Indexes -MultiViews +Includes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable SuppressHTMLPreamble
AddType text/html .php .html .htm
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
HeaderName "/~extra/HEADER.php"
```

My HEADER.php file:

```
<?php

if ( ! my_validate_cookie_function()) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
    header('Location: http://login.example.com/');
    exit(1);
}
```

So, the header isn't sent to the browser. Setting Apache environment viariables doesn't seem to work, as they are long gone the moment HEADER.php is finished executing.

The cookie itself is encrypted, hence need for PHP to validate it.

Any suggestions how to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I would suggest that it would be simpler to have an `index.php` file in the directory and have it list the files there (if authenticated). Would you like me to answer with this method?

Comment: @ScottS Please, do answer with your solution. Unfortunately at this moment it is not possible for me to put the index.php file in the directory, as it is read-only, but it seems like a reasonable solution in other cases (assuming you still use Apache to handle file downloads and not php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I finally ended up with. Kudos go to [Scott S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441523/scott-s) who hinted me towards the solution.

Apache config:

```
ServerName listing.example.com
# A path to a location which you wanted listed
DocumentRoot "/path/to/listed/location"

<Directory "/path/to/listed/location">
    # Ignore .htaccess files
    AllowOverride None
    # Disable Apache's own indexing, CGI execution and Apache Includes
    Options -Indexes -MultiViews -ExecCGI -Includes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/path/to/php/listing/app">
    Options -MultiViews ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    # index.php should not be listed here as we will not want PHP scripts to be executed
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    # This is for CSS/JS files
    Alias /~media /path/to/php/listing/app/media
</IfModule>

<IfModule xsendfile_module>
    # Because the files listed might be large, we want to pass the file handling
    # to Apache via XSendFile Module
    # @see: https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/
    XSendFile on
    XSendFilePath "/path/to/listed/location"
</IfModule>

# Uncomment the two setting below if your listing a mounted drive
# EnableSendfile Off
# EnableMMAP Off

<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Make sure there are trailing slashes for Directory URLs
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=302,L]
    # Pass all file+dir requests to a PHP handler
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule .* /path/to/php/listing/app/index.php/$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And (a very simplified version of) my php script:

```
<?php

if (my_authentication_check()) {
    $requested_path = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $filename = substr($requested_path, strrpos($requested_path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) + 1);

    if ($requested_path) {
        if (is_dir($requested_path)) {
            // Show dir contents
            $dir_contents = scandir($requested_path);
        } else {
            // Pass file download to XSendFile module
            header('X-Sendfile: ' . $requested_path);
            header('Content-Type: ' . my_get_file_mime($filename));
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        // display 404 error
    }
} else {
    // redirect to login screen, or display an error... whatever you fancy
}
```

I actually use Kohana framework with my own libraries to handle authentication checks, display the listing, etc. You will have to take file permissions into account, too. E.g. on *nix systems you will need to check dirs for executable permission, while on Windows read access is enough.

Answer (score 3):

You should insert an `index.php` file to your directory with the following code in the `<body>` tag.

```
function fileindex($folder) {
    if (!is_dir($folder)) {
        return array(); //empty if not a folder
    }
    $list = scandir($folder);
    array_shift($list); //first two values are always . & ..
    array_shift($list);
    return $list;
}
/* auth stuff here */
if (is_auth) {
    echo "<h1> Index of ".getcwd()."</h1>\n<ul>";
    echo "\n<li><a href=\"/\">Parent Directory</a>";
    foreach (fileindex(".") as $i) {
        echo "\n<li><a href=\"".$i."\">".htmlentities($i, ENT_QUOTES|"ENT_HTML401", "UTF-8", true)."</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Now since you have told me you cannot use `index.php`, you should use Apache to redirect the directory to `wherever/other.php?directory=path` and work from there.

In `.htaccess` the solution would be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wherever/other.php?directory=$1 [L]
```

Most notably, however, you would need to edit the PHP code slightly to accomodate for the folder being a `$_GET` parameter rather than a `getcwd()` and `fileindex(".")`.

Answer (score 0):

The 1 in `exit(1)` maybe the problem. Try to remove that number.

I know that `exit` is a alias for `die` and `die` prints every text to the client.

By the way I would like to suggest to use `mod_rewrite`. You can check with `RewriteCond` if the cookie exists. If you want to check more e.g. session variables this won't work.

Comment: Unfrotunately, even if I remove `exit()` completely, it doesn't work. I tried just adding a foo header, like `header('X-Foo: Bar')`, but it doesn't get sent to the browser.

Comment: Are you sure that you PHP file is executed?

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, Apache seems to be doing a separate internal request for the HEADER.php and only uses its output which is merged with file listing generated internally and output of FOOTER.php (from a gain a separate request)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<Directory "/path/to/files_root">
  DirectoryIndex redirected_page.php
</Directory>
```

Comment: This doesn't take the cookie validation into account.

Comment: It doesn't. But for security reason you have to validate your cookie in all sections of your site, so if you're doing the correct validation you don't have to worry about Apache's DirectoryIndex validation. This option is working so good for me since 2 years ago.

Comment: @VicAbreu How does that work exactly? What's the redirected_page.php in this case?

Comment: In your case will be header.php