# Redict Apache Directory Index

Tags: apache, http, redirect, directory-listing

I've got an Apache server, and I'd like to set it up such that when a directory is requested that does not have an index.html file (and thus, Apache would, by default, generate a directory listing), Apache instead redirects (ideally using [HTTP code 303](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303)) to a given url.

Unless absolutely necessary, I'd like to stay away from going outside Apache (for example, by having Apache load a php script which writes the headers manually). This is an otherwise static site, and I'd like to avoid having to introduce scripting languages into the mix.

Also, note that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980579/how-to-redirect-apache-index-of-page) doesn't solve my problem since all of the proposed solutions use external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that by using a combination of HTML `meta` refreshing and JavaScript redirection, I could cover almost all browsers in use and still have a static file. So what I did was this. In the apache site config, I put a directive that told apache to first look for `index.html` files, and if that failed, use a site-wide `/no-index.html`:

```
<Directory /path/to/web/root>
    DirectoryIndex index.html /no-index.html
</Directory>
```

`no-index.html`, then, contained the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "/";
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

(in this example it redirects to the web root, `/`, but you could replace that with whatever url you wanted)

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) for an explanation of what the `<meta>` tag is doing.